# Convert/add string to a specific type

Tags: arrays, swift

I would like to convert/add a string to a type [Talent.Otherlanguages]

Talent.Otherlanguages is an enum who contain many languages.

I would like to do this : otherlanguages?.append(Talent.Otherlanguage(rawValue: langue)!)

but when i do print(otherlanguages) the value is set to nil.
Do any of you have an idea to help me ?

Comment: Show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

In case you consider `otherlanguages` is `nil` it is my assamtion. Because if you send wrong `rawValue` to the `enum` constructor you going to receive crash.So you are not checking if `otherlanguages` is not nil and try to append something.

This is example:

```
enum Languages:String {
    case uk = "english "
    case ua = "ukrainian"
}

var languages = [Languages]()

print(languages) //[]

languages.append(Languages(rawValue: "ukrainian")!)

print(languages) //[Languages.ua]
```